# How to configure Adminer to be reachable on the local network

Tags: networking, apache2, webserver

I have currently configured a Ubuntu web development server machine, but am having problems connecting/viewing Adminer on the local network. e.g. I can connect to Apache without any problems from a different machine using the local network IP e.g. 172.16.0.24/index.php fine. But when I try to access 172.16.0.24/adminer i get the:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /adminer was not found on this server.
```

On the Ubuntu web development server machine, i can access adminer via 127.0.0.1 on localhost. e.g. 127.0.0.1/adminer, the same as Apache.

I would like to know what would be the correct config, to make adminer reachable without playing around with my DNS/host settings on the other networked computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found on Ubuntu 16.04 that after installing **Adminer** via

```
sudo apt-get install adminer
```

it didn't correctly set up the **Adminer** Apache configuration file. I did the following to get it working:

```
cd /etc/apache2/conf-available
sudo ln -s ../../adminer/apache.conf adminer.conf
sudo a2enconf adminer
sudo service apache2 reload
```

After that the it worked locally and remotely for me

Comment: Yup I had the same issue in Ubuntu 16.04. The apt install script for Adminer is buggy.

Comment: I had same issue and with above steps it worked ! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think viewing just the file will solve the problem. At least mine didn't.  If you installed Adminer through the command line like this `sudo apt-get install adminer`, the apache configuration will be found in `/etc/adminer/apache.conf` file.

You have to **Include** this configuration file in your apache configuration which is usually found in */etc/apache2/apache2.conf* file. If so, through the command line type `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and at the bottom of the file add `Include /etc/adminer/apache.conf` or the file path your adminer configuration. Restart your apache server by typing `sudo service apache2 restart`. If you browse for localhost/adminer you should get everything up and running like this.

[image: Final screenshot of Adminer up and running]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You can improve your answer by including the command needed to restart `Apache`. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed those who know about Adminer should already familiar with restarting apache server. By the way, I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: By viewing the file in /etc/apache2/conf-available named: adminer.conf.

This then contains the Alias names, the file reads:

```
Alias /adminer.php /usr/share/adminer/adminer.php
```

I then went onto the other machine on my network and typed in:

http://172.16.0.24/adminer.php

And it worked!